# Can <security-constraint> tag in web.xml be dynamically generated or written outside web.xml?

Tags: web.xml, security-constraint

I met a problem, I want to set the tag of security-constraint according to my configuration file dynamically, but I can't do it. So I hope  tag in web.xml can be dynamically generated or written outside web.xml. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think your question could be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979739/dynamic-security-constraint-configuration-in-java-web-xml) one. However, if you were working with Servlet 3.0 spec, you could try the approach of programmatically adding and configuring security for the servlet, as shown [here](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kumarjayanti/archive/2009/12/28/summary-new-security-features-servlet-30).

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I want to decide if authenticating or not according to my config file on disk. Before I start my web app, I need make security-constraint tag moved or reserved in web.xml after checking config file. But my web app started as a osgi bundle service, I can't fetch and modify web.xml, so I wonder if security-constraint tag can be written into an external xml file which can be modified dynamically, or if securty-constraint tag can be generated only when i need it.

Comment: If this is the case, you should try the Filter way, assuming you can configure it in the web.xml.